# requestLayout() improperly called by RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have a custom `FrameLayout` and in xml file it has 2 child (both of them are `RelativeLayout` and they overlap each other)

In `drawChild` method I do this

```
 protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    if(view.equals(firstChild){
       return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }else {
     //...do some thing with mPath like adding a circle to it
     canvas.clipPath(mPath);
     return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
   }
}
```

But I got these two lines from Logcat:

```
requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.RelativeLayout{c1a8b57 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,210} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.RelativeLayout{c1a8b57 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,210} during layout: running second layout pass
```

I know there is something wrong with `clipPath` (maybe overlapping) because the warning disappears by commenting this line  `canvas.clipPath(mPath);`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: "if i change the visibility of second child to GONE",  this would cause the 2nd child to never get measured, laidout, and drawn.

Comment: @petey yeah i know, i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

There are three thigs I would do:

First of  all, I would check the compatibility canvas.clipPath() with your target API version, it should be 18 or higher.

Second, I would check where and how you declare Path object(mPath).

Third, I would make sure that canavas already exist by the time you trying to clipPath().  Also, it might not be the issue, but according to API for FrameLayout: Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top, so make sure the child you are working with is accessible.